# AWS cross-account access issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been struggling with a seemingly basic issue wherein a customer requires access to an s3 bucket which is in a different account that they typically access, for some upcoming migration work.

My aws knowledge is basic, but I think the issue is proving a little difficult as this user is a 'federated user' and they are assuming a role from a different aws account (this role is named something like `AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_67237874g479d_emailexample@email.com` which is setup/managed in a central aws account we also overlook).

I have tried updating the inline policy of the s3 bucket like so, to allow access to it from the role he is accessing from, by grabbing its ARN directly from the AWS dashboard...

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
       {
          "Sid": "PermissionsForExampleAccount",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::868990465:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_67237874g479d"
          },
          "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:Get*"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::example-data",
            "arn:aws:s3:::example-data/*"
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

The problem is when I try and save this, I get an error message telling me the resource is invalid and the ARN is invalid. How can this be if I've copied the role's ARN directly? and does it look like there is something off with the resource also?

And I guess as a second question... if I get these errors cleared and the inline policy updated... what other steps are needed to provide this customer access? (i.e. how does the customer access the s3 bucket/aws account from his side once this issue is sorted... I'm guessing I'll need to add something to the role he accesses from too?).

I would love step-by-step instructions to work through the issue as its a little confusing. Thanks for reading, and sorry for the lack of knowledge, any help is welcome!!

Comment: Try it without the `_67237874g479d` bit at the end.

Comment: It is complaining that the resource is also invalid so it is hard to test... do you see anything wrong with the resource part?

Comment: Is that a real Role ARN? Because the Account Number `868990465` seems to be too short. It is normally 12 digits.

Comment: No John, I have actually changed this number for security reasons rather than exposing the actual account number

Comment: The role you show has been created by IAM Identity Center, which is different to IAM. I suspect that it is a temporary role that changes name with each login (hence the digits at the end). This _might_ assist: [Allow SSO User Access to S3 Bucket in Another Account with their identitystore:UserId | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUpS_5uoExQqujbTTe02zGSA/allow-sso-user-access-to-s3-bucket-in-another-account-with-their-identitystore-userid)

Comment: *"I get an error message telling me the resource is invalid and the ARN is invalid."* What is the exact text of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your AWS account is not going to be aware of the other accounts ARN from within your S3 permissions.  The approach to use is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html#tutorial_cross-account-with-roles-2
Essentially you are setting up an assume role that allows the other account to access, and within that role you give it access to the bucket.

Comment: Interestingly, the Policy Editor seems to be aware of which Account Numbers are 'real' -- typing a random one will give an error, but typing a known one will remove the error. However, it would not be able to detect whether a named policy exists.